# Can I travel without BRP but with an ILR stamp in my old passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

I really need some help here. My BRP was stolen a few days ago by a pickpocket. I have reported the matter to the police and the home office's website. I do intend to replace it.

However I will be travelling next week (bearing in mind it'll be the long Easter weekend) this week, thus getting a premium service appointment is near impossible, unless I am willing to pay an additional another extra £75 on top of the £640 premium service fee! I do still have my old ILR stamp in my old expired passport.

Can I still travel back to the UK with this? Will I have an issue getting a replacement BRP the normal way when I'm back?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: BRP? ILR? I guess anyone who knows the answer will know what those abbreviations mean, but it would be helpful if you said what they stand for.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm _American_ and I know what they both mean. ILR is Indefinite Leave to Remain. BRP is the biometric residence permit that has been issued over the last several years. AFAIK, if you have a ILR sticker in your old passport, that says RESIDENCE PERMIT and looks somewhat like the current residence permits, that is valid to enter with. But I'm not 100% sure of that, so I'm not making it an answer right now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am quite sure that you are among a tiny minority of Americans who know what those things mean.

Comment: Those abbreviations are common knowledge on this site, but expanding them does help others who are searching the web.

Comment: As an aside to the asker: why do you feel the need to carry the card in your pocket? The UK does not require that. Once you get the replacement, I suggest leaving it at home unless you specifically need it.

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.

Answer (score -1):

You have two issues: no BRP and an expired passport. While your ILR is in the passport, that document is no longer valid and, without the BRP which contains your visa details, it is unlikey you would be allowed [entry into the UK](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control). It requires both a valid passport and BRP.

As an aside, leaving the UK, where would you be able to travel? Without any valid travel documents, a carrier may not allow you to board, although some might for travel directly to your country of origin (should it allow entry with expired passport)?

Comment: I think we can assume that the asker *also* has a valid passport.